# Most efficient way to list all categories and display a post for each of them?

Tags: posts, categories, optimization

I'm working on a blog that has around 8.000 posts and 50 categories.

The task I'm working on is to list all categories and for each category to show the latest post with a certain custom field value.

My current approach is to get all the categories, loop through them and for each one do a wp_query to find the latest post.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, one that doesn't involve running 50 queries on the page?

Comment: I don't have the time to write up the code at the moment, but a hint off the top of my head would be to do it on the admin side when a new post is published (or deleted), save all of your rendered posts data in an option, then you can just load that single option on the front end.

Comment: Thank you @Milo, I haven't thought of that. If you'll write this comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.